# Prisma DateTime Format Issue

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I was practicing around with Nest Js and prisma and i wanted to store DateTime in database according to my timezone. `

```
joining      DateTime     @db.Timestamptz(5)
```

`
Adding the @db.Timestamptz fixed my issue for storing the timezone specific time. But when I get it back from the db it automatically changes into GMT in the format **2022-12-01T06:56:54.240Z**

Any ideas on why is this happening?

I'm new to Nest and Prisma. So i don't have any idea on what's up with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prisma Client returns all DateTime as native [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects. The time would be stored in the UTC format in the database. See this section of the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#datetime). Storing DateTime in UTC is standard practice, so you shouldn’t face any issues.
This is especially useful when the frontend needs to show times in different timezones; for these cases, the database should use one standard time format.